# Derivation of the radial Hartree-Fock equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics

Can anyone help deriving the radial Hartree-Fock equations of atoms from the Hartree-Fock equations
$$(h_i + J_i - K_i) \psi_i = E_i \psi_i$$
where each orbital $\psi_i$ involves three space coordinates? I'm interested in the restricted Hartree-Fock formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found the following formula
$$
\frac{1}{\vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'\vert} =
\sum_{k,q} \frac{r_<^k}{r_>^{k+1}} \frac{4\pi}{2k+1} Y_{kq}(\Omega) Y_{kq}^*(\Omega')
$$
in [this page](https://www.theoretical-physics.net/dev/quantum/hf.html). That's all what I need for helium.